# Drop last word in pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column full of addresses. In general, I have inconsistent formatting and want to make the formatting consistent.

as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'apt': [1, 2, 3], 'unit': ['f', 'g', 'a'], 'address: 
['15 E 59th St', '4 4th St', '4 83rd street']})
```

I am currently formatting my column as so:

```
df['address'] = df['address'].str.title().str.replace(r"(\d+) 
(st|nd|rd|th)\b", r"\1")
```

to remove "ordinality" from the street numbers. However, sometimes the address ends in an abbreviation 'st' and sometimes the full word 'street' and I think simply removing the last word of each string would be the easiest way to get around this. How can I do this in a Pythonic way so that I am applying something to the entire column that removes the last word? I've tried rsplit and it won't work the way I have it:

```
df['address'].str.title().str.replace(r"(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)\b", 
r"\1").str.rsplit([' ', 1])[0]
```

Edit: the current answer is very helpful, but I have realized that dropping the street type actually won't work in a few cases where a street and avenue have the same beginning (1 st and 1 ave). Is there a way to make the street endings consistent so that all versions of all street endings are the same?

Comment: concat a word with the answer given `df.address.str.rsplit(' ',1).str[0]+" Street"` you will have all streets with same ending.

Comment: They aren't all streets, some are ave blvd, ave, etc.

Comment: exactly, so then you have to have a set of all such instances and expected replacement if you have to get this via pandas. :)

Answer (score 10):

Doing with `str.rsplit`

```
df.address.str.rsplit(' ',1).str[0]
0    15 E 59th
1        4 4th
2       4 83rd
Name: address, dtype: object
df.address=df.address.str.rsplit(' ',1).str[0]
```